# Python скрипт парсинга Вконтакте. Имя сохраняемого файла

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Помогите доработать `python` скрипт для парсинга участников группы Вконтакте, пожалуйста. Сейчас он сохраняет результат в виде `club[id группы].txt`. Хочется добавить еще название группы в имя сохраняемого файла. Насколько я понимаю, для этого нужно сделать дополнительный [запрос](https://api.vk.com/method/groups.getById?group_id=12345), в `json` ответе будет строка `name: "КИРИШИ CLUB"`. Подскажите, как ее вычленить и добавить к имени файла?

```
import requests
import time as t 
import csv
from datetime import datetime, date, time, timedelta

token = 'xxxx'


def write_txt(members_list, owner_id):    
a = open('club'+str(owner_id)+'.txt', 'w')
for i in members_list:
    a.write(str(i)+'\n') #писать мож
a.close() 

def get_members_list_id(owner_id):
print('Начал работать в:',datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), "%H:%M:%S"))

members_list =  [] #изначально пустой список участников

#первый запрос на 25000, чтобы получить первые 25000 и количество участников группы
r = requests.post('https://api.vk.com/method/execute.Shmakov_getClub_members?group_id='+
                  str(owner_id)+'&offset='+str(0)+'&count='+str(25000)+'&access_token='+token).json()['response']
members_count = r[0] #количество участников


print('Участников:',members_count)

members_list.extend(r[1]) #вносим первые 25000 ID 

if members_count > 25000:
    print('Больше 25k участников. Запускаем цикл')
    for offset in range(25000, members_count, 25000):
        count = offset + 25000

        r = requests.post('https://api.vk.com/method/execute.Shmakov_getClub_members?group_id='+
                         str(owner_id)+'&offset='+str(offset)+'&count='+str(count)+'&access_token='+token).json()['response']

        members_list.extend(r[1]) #вносим все последующие ID пачками по 25000 ID


        #t.sleep(.35) #задержки между запросом --- ВАЖНО: если будут возникать проблемы - расскоментировать 
    print('Цербер закончил сбор ID')
else:
    print('>25k участников. Закончили сбор ID')

print(len(members_list))
write_txt(members_list, owner_id) #записываем по 25000 ID
print('Данные успешно записаны')
print('Остановка:',datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), "%H:%M:%S"))


get_ipython().magic('time get_members_list_id(12345)')
```

Comment: А что за `execute.Shmakov_getClub_members`? Это какая то функция вашего приложения?

Comment: Почему бы не пользоваться вк API для python? Зачем вы всё делаете реквестами?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import requests

req = requests.post(r'https://api.vk.com/method/groups.getById?group_id={0}'.format(owner_id))

print(req.json()['response'][0]['name'])
```

Результат:

```
КИРИШИ CLUB
```

Что бы подставить это в имя файла можно к примеру сделать так:

```
import requests
owner_id = 12345
req = requests.post(r'https://api.vk.com/method/groups.getById?group_id={0}'.format(owner_id)).json()['response'][0]['name']
file_name = open('{0}_{1}.txt'.format(req, owner_id), 'w')
```

На выходе получим файл:

```
КИРИШИ CLUB_12345.txt
```

**UODATE**

Чтобы убрать все лишние символы с названия группы:

```
In [25]: import re

In [26]: pub_name = 'VK "", "", "!?,@#$%^&*_+|+\/:;[]{}<>") Public'

In [27]: re.sub(r'[\W+_]', '', pub_name)
Out[27]: 'VKPublic'
```